# slicing the pandas data frame with month range

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am working on a dataset which has a years data on a pandas data frame. The sample is given below. The data is indexed on the Date column

```
DATE                   
2013-12-07  6555  10171
2013-06-17  3754  11140
2013-10-02  5278   6986
2014-01-26  4493  10432
2013-11-17  6739   9001
2014-02-28  3708  11540
2013-04-16   262   6616
2013-08-29  5247   7062
2013-09-18  4401   7032
2013-06-13  2739   7386
2014-03-04  5247  11140
2013-07-22  5047   8647
2013-04-04   277   6447
2013-08-09  5508   7155
2013-11-13  5632   9201
```

I would like to get a a sample of 3 months and 6 months from the data frame. Please do advice on how best I could achieve it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `pandas.TimeGrouper(freq='3M')` and `pandas.TimeGrouper(freq='6M')`?

Comment: Hi Emil, Thanks for your comment. I was thinking the it does aggregation. But here I just want a three month sample starting from the first date and a six month sample data without aggregation. Could timegrouper achieve it? I tried using date_ranges and the ix function. It kind of worked.

Comment: You could also do it with something like `df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month > 6]).groups` not sure what the proper way is though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to extract a 3/6 month chunk of data from your data frame why not truncate?

Assuming your dataframe is called "df":

```
# 3 month chunk
df3 = df.truncate(df.index[0],df.index[0]+3)

# 6 month chunk
df6 = df.truncate(df.index[0],df.index[0]+6)
```

There is some ambiguity in your question, so I wonder if you mean to do a 3/6 month resampling.  If so, it is also quite easy.

```
df3 = df.resample('3M',how='mean',axis=0)
df6 = df.resample('6M',how='mean',axis=0)
```